# If $\mathbf x\in \mathbb R ^n$ is a unit vector, why $\mathbf x^TN\mathbf x =1$ where $N$ is positive-definite and symmetrical?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N$ be a $n\times n$ real symmetric and positive-definite matrix, and let $\mathbf x$ be a unit vector that satisfies $A\mathbf x = \lambda N\mathbf x$, where $A$ is a real symmetric matrix. Then 
$$\langle \mathbf x, N\mathbf x\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf x_i N_{ij_{1\le j\le n}}\mathbf x = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf x_i \sum_{j=1}^nN_{ij}\mathbf x_j.$$

I don't understand why the last sum should be $1$ as stated [here in the Simultaneous diagonalization section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe the page implies it is normalized with respect to $N$.

Comment: @Uldreth, yes I just added the definition of $\mathbf x$. Sorry about that.

Comment: You misunderstand me, I believe, if and only if I interpret the wikipedia page properly, that we *define* $\mathbf{x}$ to be normalized with respect to $N$. $N$ is a symmetric, positive bilinear form, so it is a bit like an inner product. If a vector is normalized w.r.t an inner product, it means $\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle=1$. If it is normalized w.r.t a bilinear form $N$, it means $N(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=1$.

Comment: @Uldreth. I kind of get what you are saying, however I would like to see that $N(\mathbf x,\mathbf x)=1$ more explicitly.

Comment: More explicitly? Well, take your favourite vector, $\mathbf{y}$, that isn't the 0 vector, then take $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}/\sqrt{N(\mathbf{y,y})}$. Now if you take $N(\mathbf{x,x})$, you'll get $N(\mathbf{x,x})=N(\mathbf{y,y})/N(\mathbf{y,y})=1$, so there you go, you have $N(\mathbf{x,x})=1$ :) .